# Google maps V3 resizing with media query not centerings after change

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code for maps on a blank page:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    var map;

    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Business Location'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });

</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEYM&signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I want the map to change to a set size on browser width like this:

```
#map {     // Full screen
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 970px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1281px) {    // Smaller width screen
  #map {
    width: 480px;
  }
}
```

The resizing works via media query but it does not trigger the map reload / center.

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Which upon further research I understand that none of the map methods can be called until initMap has run (as this is async load). Not sure how to address this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main problems with your code I can see. Firstly, you're calling the initMap function in two separate places:

The callback parameter when you load the google maps JS:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEYM&signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

And also on window load:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Don't do that, only do it using one of these methods, otherwise you'll call the function twice, creating two maps and that'll just lead to problems.

Secondly, you create a  **global** `map` variable, which is fine, when you do `var map;`.  However you then create a new **local** variable in the initMap function, which is only accessible to that function:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...)
```

So then when you try and access that again in your event listener for the map resize (with `map.getCenter()` etc), all you're getting is the **global** variable, which at this point is a null object, rather than the **local** variable which is the actual Map object.

Here's what I'd amend your code to:

```
<script>
    var map;

    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Business Location'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEYM&signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I'd also maybe move the window resize event listener into the initMap function, so you're only referencing the map object after you know you've created it.

Comment: Hi @duncan, awesome response, thanks! I just moved the event listener into init funciton and voila! Perfect. Your code worked like a charm. You rock man!